# How to update nested array inside an Object in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to update `progress` of the particular course by finding `userId` and `coursename`. I have seen all the MongoDB queries for that but still not getting the desired output. Sometimes got an empty array while data exist in DB. I am not getting if I have to add value inside the progress array then how I will apply the MongoDB query on that:

```
{
    userId: "218u092ue029ie",
    ABC:{
        "courseName": "course1",
        "progress": [
            1,2,3
        ]
    },
    XYZ:{
        "courseName": "course2",
        "progress": [
            1,2
        ]
    },
    pqr:{
        "courseName": "course3",
        "progress": [
            1,2,3,4,5
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
db.yourCollection.updateOne(
{ userId: "218u092ue029ie", "ABC.courseName": "course1" },
{ $set: { "ABC.progress.$": [1, 2, 3, 4] } }
```

);